# How do I partition a sequence into varying-length tuples according to an existing pattern distribution?

Tags: python, algorithm, nlp

I have a prior probability distribution for various parts of speech patterns, held in `patterns`. I also have a sequence of lists of parts of speech tokens, obtained from word tokenization, in `sequences`.

I would like to partition each list in `sequences` into any number of disjoint segments, where each segment exists in `patterns` and the joint probability is maximized.

For example, the sequence `['NN', 'VBG', 'CC', 'VBG']` would ideally be partitioned into the following: `[('NN',), ('VBG',), ('VBG',)]`.

I can't think of an approach that isn't horribly inefficient. Perhaps if `patterns` were organized in some sort of tree structure would help?

```
patterns = {('NN',): 0.40132345717065276,
            ('VBG',): 0.22273379631859294,
            ('JJ', 'NN'): 0.075111492116086656,
            ('NN', 'NN'): 0.056656296053708859,
            ...
            ('NN', 'NN', 'VBG'): 0.00039491807857906547,
            ('RB', 'VBD'): 0.00033712518903090955,
            ('NN', 'CD'): 0.00019264296516051976,
            ('VBG', 'NN'): 0.0017337866864446778}

sequences = [['NN', 'VBG', 'CC', 'VBG'],
             ['JJ', 'NNS', 'VBP', 'RB', 'JJ', 'JJ', 'NN'],
             ['JJ', 'NN'],
             ['JJ', 'NNP', 'JJ', 'NNS']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view this as a word segmentation problem and solve it efficiently through dynamic programming. Think of your sequence of PoS tags as words that are **not** separated by space (as is the case in Chinese). The task is to insert the "spaces" so that the words "make sense".

I will be using the following terminology:

- Every PoS tag is a `character`
- Every sequence of PoS tags, e.g. `NN` or `(JJ NN)`, is a `word`, consisting of `characters`.
- Every word `w` has a score, `s(w)`. This is implemented by your `patterns` dict. `s(w') = 0` for all unknown words `w'`
- The score of a segmentation is a combination (e.g. the sum) of the scores of all words in the segmentation

We need a few things to get to an algorithm:

- An array `B[i]` that stores the best possible score of a segmentation of the first `i` characters
- An arrary `L[i]` that specifies where the last gap (space between words) prior to character `i` is
- `B[0] = 0` and `B[1] = s(c_0)`, where `c_0` is the first character
- `P[0] = 0`
- `B[i] = max(B[j] + s(c_j...c_i))` for all `0 < j < i`, where `c_j...c_i` is the word formed by all characters from position `i` to position `j` inclusive.

The algorithm is as follows:

```
B[0] = 0
B[1] = s(sequence[0:1])
for i in 0...len(sequence):
    B[i] = 0
    for j in 0...i:
        candidate = s(sequence[i:j]) + B[j]
        if candidate > B[i]:
           B[i] = candidate
           P[i] = j
for beg, end in consecutive_pairs(P): #
    print c_beg...c_end
```

This pseudocode populates `B` with optimal scores, and `P` with the positions of the "spaces".

Things to note:

- This solution is optimal with respect to a given score function `s`. Looking at your question, `s(NN) + s(NN) >> s(NN NN)`. This means it is better for the sequence `NN NN` to be segmented as two words `(NN, NN)` rather than as the single word `(NN NN,)`. You might have to tweak your score function.
- Setting the score of unknown words to 0 is intentional. This ensures `NN CC NN` is segmented as three words `(NN, CC, NN)` rather than as `(NN CC, NN)` or `(NN, CC NN)` or `(NN CC NN,)`. This may or may not be what you want, please edit your question if it isn't
- It's possible that my indexing is off by one, I'm too tired to tell right now. The code above should be enough to get you started. This is a standard algorithm, feel free to refer to whichever textbook you prefer.

Comment: Great! I'd not thought of it in terms of word segmentation. Instead, I kept thinking about it in terms of set partitioning and similar approaches. Let me have a crack at implementing this, and I'll get back to accept the solution. One thing: `L` (last gap array) appears to become `P` later in your pseudo-code.